# Embedding Watermarks in VirtualDub - Watermark suddenly is blue

Tags: virtualdub, watermark

What happened to my logo?

Take a look at

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZQlVRPFshs
>
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VR58GQr3wV8

See the logo in the bottom-right corner? It's this image:
[image]
 it's a watermark.bmp. It's not blue, it's red.

I'm using this to embed the logo

[image].

It's the ffdshow filter from http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net. I'm always using the latest version. And for transcoding I use http://komisar.gin.by/.

Why is my logo suddenly blue?!

Comment: Has it really become blue all of a sudden? Does it happen to all files you encode from now on, or is there a random pattern? I can't see why it would randomly do that.

Comment: Yes, all of a sudden. I mean my latest video encoded was http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9G-tV6gbcg8 , it still was red there. Now it's blue all of a sudden. Yes, happens to all files I encode.

Comment: What I mean is, does it happen for subsequent encodings too?

Comment: Yes, for every encoding. No matter what video I choose to transcode, it always is blue from now on.

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a change in color spaces.

Let's take a simple example: Maybe you were reading the logo as `RGB` before. The red portions were stored as `0xFF0000`. You could also store it as `BGR`- and there you would have your swapped red and blue values because the `FF` part would be interpreted as the blue portion instead of the red one.

Even worse, the video will be converted to `YUV` instead, where colors could be mixed up even more, since it's now partitioned in Luma and Chroma instead of raw color values.

What I'd suggest is:

- Find the settings for input/output colorspaces and try to experiment with that. Maybe something was mixed up here.
- Save a new version of your watermark, maybe with another program.